# Ubuntu Broken after Interrupted Software Update

Tags: 12.04, wireless, updates, ethernet, macbook-pro

I was working while the Ubuntu Software Update prompt popped up, yet again. I was very annoyed by its constant appearance, so I decided to authorize the update. It started, and after a few minutes, with the prompt in a different workspace, my computer froze, with me only being able to move my mouse. I left it for about a minute to be sure, then force shutdown the computer. When I started up again, everything was broken. Instead of my menu buttons in the upper right corner, I had only a red circle with the white bar (error symbol). Upon click, it prompted me to perform a partial update. Additionally, my touchpad stopped working, and when I checked the Network section in System Settings, neither Wired nor Wireless was there. After the partial update completed, another restart didn't bring me into a lightdm login screen but instead a command line. I logged on from the command line, and "sudo lightdm" couldn't manually start the display either; just stuck on a lightdm log.

EDIT: It no longer can boot (stuck at startup screen, recovery mode stuck after mounting root file system), I'm trying to copy rEFInd onto a USB and boot from the USB.

My computer is a MacBook Pro (late 2009), and my distribution is 12.04 Precise Pangolin.

Thank you for helping! I will try to copy the data onto a hard drive and do a backup, but meanwhile, if there is any other solution other than reinstalling, it would be really helpful.

Comment: In terminal try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: No internet connection, that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

if you are at least medium user, I'll suggest to make sure you have enough space on your root (/) partition

and try to perform these steps

http://www.isysop.com/using-fixit-and-chroot-to-repair-a-non-booting-system/

or

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=157250

if not, then backup your data and reinstall the system, but next time you install new system, please provide dedicated partition for **/home** directory, in this way your data and personal settings are safe on reinstalation, and for **/** set a partition with at least 10gb (15 gb is better) and eq. of your RAM for swap

plus, broken instalation operations usually are fixed with

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

if you can boot up your system

Comment: I've tried "apt-get install -f". However, /home is already on a separate partition now, does that mean I can reinstall and preserve my data without any problems? Thanks!

Comment: yes, but when you install your new system select ex-home's partition as partition for new-home and DON'T-CHECK format this partition :) and, when asked provide same password and username as in previous instalation, in this way you'll get everything back to normal without problems. 

BUT! if you are doing it first time, I suggest to make a backup, to be sure you don't loose anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reminders! I finally managed to do a backup (Fedora+ssh+scp) of important files, and I will erase the other partitions preventing my liveUSB's from booting up, thanks.